# Facing "MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key" Error with Face++ API Despite Verified Header and Documentation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm struggling with a persistent error while using the Face++ API compare endpoint:

> "MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key"

I've double-checked the Authorization header structure and values numerous times, including verifying against the official documentation, but the error persists.

What I've tried:

Verified the format of the Authorization header: `Face++ <API key>:<API secret>`.
Confirmed consistent single/double quotes usage around the header string.
Reviewed the Face++ API documentation for the compare endpoint regarding header requirements.

[image: error]

[image: code]